# "location path" Unrecognized element error on web-config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, wif

I'm doing a SSO implementation with WIF for my application on IIS.
I've been requested to add a Default.aspx page with a link to the Login one (and so to the SSO Login page).

To do this, I'm following the documentation provided to me for this implementation and I added two location path tags to the web-config.

These are the tags I added (following the documentation):

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
     <system.web>
         <authorization>
             <allow users="?" />
         </authorization>
     </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="WebResource.axd">
     <system.web>
         <authorization>
             <allow users="?" />
         </authorization>
     </system.web>
  </location>
```

Here the full web-config as requested in comment:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppNameConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DataSourceName;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DbNetSuiteLicenseKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <!--<add key="DbNetSuiteSymmetricKeyName" value="" />
    <add key="DbNetSuiteCertificateName" value="" />-->
    <add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://metadatalink/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>   
  <location path="WebResource.axd">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <allow users="?"/>
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <pages styleSheetTheme="AppName" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="dx" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor" assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v17.1" />
        <add tagPrefix="dx" namespace="DevExpress.Web" assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add tagPrefix="lc" namespace="Lightcode.Framework.Presentation.Web.UI.Blocks" assembly="Framework.Presentation.Web" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
          symbols into the compiled page. Because this
          affects performance, set this value to true only
          during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.SpellChecker.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v17.1.Web, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Charts.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
    </httpModules>
    <globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx" />
      <!--Modifica Fabio-->
      <add name="dbnetgrid_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetgrid.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetGrid" />
      <add name="dbnetedit_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetedit.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetEdit" />
      <add name="dbnetfile_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetfile.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetFile" />
      <add name="dbnetspell_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetspell.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetSpell" />
      <add name="dbnetcombo_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetcombo.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetCombo" />
      <add name="dbnetlist_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetlist.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.DbNetList" />
      <add name="dbnetsuite_js_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetsuite.js.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.JS" />
      <add name="dbnetsuite_css_ashx" verb="*" path="dbnetsuite.css.ashx" type="DbNetLink.DbNetSuite.CSS" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <devExpress>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="false" />
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" baseColor="" font="" />
    <settings doctypeMode="Xhtml" rightToLeft="false" embedRequiredClientLibraries="false" ieCompatibilityVersion="8" accessibilityCompliant="false" bootstrapMode="Bootstrap3" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" protectControlState="true" />
  </devExpress>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://server/AppName/Login.aspx" />
      </audienceUris>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://idptest/adfs/ls/" realm="https://server/AppName/Login.aspx" requireHttps="true" />
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      </serviceCertificate>
      <applicationService>
        <claimTypeRequired>
          <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'http://idptest/adfs/services/trust'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/denyonlysid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/denyonlyprimarysid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/denyonlyprimarygroupsid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarygroupsid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/isregistereduser" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/identifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/registrationid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/displayname" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/ostype" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/osversion" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/ismanaged" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-application" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-user-agent" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-client-ip" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-endpoint-absolute-path" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-proxy" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/relyingpartytrustid" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/applicationpolicy" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/authoritykeyidentifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/basicconstraints" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/eku" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuer" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuername" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/keyusage" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/notafter" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/notbefore" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatepolicy" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/rsa" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/rawdata" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/san" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/serialnumber" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/signaturealgorithm" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/subject" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/subjectkeyidentifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/subjectname" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatetemplateinformation" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/extension/certificatetemplatename" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/x509version" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/insidecorporatenetwork" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationtime" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordexpirationdays" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01/passwordchangeurl" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/client-request-id" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2013/11/alternateloginid" optional="true" />-->
        </claimTypeRequired>
      </applicationService>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" name="http://idptest/adfs/services/trust" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

When I try to reach the application, i get an "Unrecognized element" error on the first location tag (the Default.aspx one).

I'm not very practiced with this kind of things, so I'm not sure if the problem could be an IIS setting who is missing or something missing on the web-config, or something else.

[Error message snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0AKk.png)

Comment: You need to paste the complete web.config file. Merely this portion won't reveal what's wrong.

Comment: Now added to the post.

Comment: Could you share the error message snapshot?

Comment: Sure, added the link to the post.

Comment: try to remove <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>   part from web.config and try again to access site.

Comment: Obviously if i'll remove that part it will work, but it won't meet the implementation requirements because the site will be automatically redirected to the SSO Login page.
I need to get to the Default.aspx page before the SSO Login page.